# C bytes of a char pointer in memory

Tags: c, pointers, allocation

I would like to count how many bytes a char pointer takes in memory.
The pointer points to a string with 100 chars.

According to the following program a char needs 4 bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char b;
  b = 'b';
  printf("%p\n",&b);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Is it the same for pointers?
So it's 400 bytes saved in memory for a string of 100 chars?

Comment: Question makes no sense - how does printing the *address* of a char variable tall you anything about the size of a pointer ?

Comment: The code you post says nothing about the size of anything. Please clarify if you're asking about the size of pointers to chars, the thing pointed to by a pointer, or something else.

Comment: Don't print the contents of a pointer with %d this is for `int`. Pointers may not have the same width as `int`. %p is the correct format for them.

Comment: `sizeof(&b)` or even just `sizeof(char*)` is a better method of determine the width of a specific pointer type for any particular architecture.  You are relying on the formatting of %p to infer the width, but that may be misleading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`char` needs one byte. Pointer to anything usually needs 4 or 8 bytes depending on the architecture. Of course an object and a pointer to it are separate things and they use separate memory, so if a 100-char string uses 100 or 101 byte (depends on how do you count and how do you store the string), a pointer to it will still use 4 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

No, for a string of 100 chars you need 100 bytes + 1 byte for '\0' string terminator.
Your program returns 4-byte integer because you are printing value of the pointer to char.
Char has a size of 1 byte and does not depend on architecture. Size of a pointer depends on architecture and, typically, 4-byte for 32 bit archs and 8-byte for 64 bit ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your program prints the memory address of the space allocated for b. It's not related to the amount of memory reserved.

To see the amount of memory a pointer takes in memory, you can use sizeof(void*). The value depends on the system, I guess in yours it's 4 (32 bits)

However you cannot get the amount of allocated memory a pointer points at (e.g. through malloc). In the general case you need to store this during allocation. In some cases such as string duplication through strdup(), it will be equal to the length of the string + 1 (for the ending '\0' character.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you've not got the concepts of pointers vs what they point to clear yet - which to be fair can be tricky to start.

To try and rephrase, a pointer is something that holds the address or location of some other element.  Depending upon the system you're running on, the amount of memory need by a pointer itself will vary, but will typically be 4 or 8 bytes.  That's separate from the memory use by what it points to, which could be anything from zero, if it's a null pointer, upwards.  (By the way, there's no standard way to find the size of what a pointer's pointing to, but that's another topic.)

Anyway, if you had a string of 100 chars, you'd expect to allocate a buffer of 101 chars (as a matter of habit, allow space for and add a terminating null, just in case you do actually get the full 100 chars), so your program's memory usage would be in the order of 105 or 109 bytes for the buffer and a single pointer to it.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the pointer to `char` type is `sizeof (int *)` bytes.

The value is implementation defined but is usually 4 bytes in 32-bit system and 8 bytes in 64-bit system. To print the size on your system, you can do:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof (char *));
```

The size of the `char` type is always 1 byte.

The size of a string is `sizeof the_string_array_object` bytes. For example, the size of the string `"Hello world!"` is `sizeof "Hello world!"` bytes. It is the number of character in the string including the trailing null character.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is an address to a memory location.  A 100 byte string occupies 100 memory locations.  Because they are contiguous, you can reference the string with a single pointer, but it still occupies 100 memory locations.

If this were a street, the string is analogous to a row of houses, each one has a separate address, but you might refer to all of them by the street name; that is analogous to the string name or pointer referring to a string of locations rather than, an individual location.  The street still occupies the same space however!

A pointer in this case is 4 bytes because a 32bit processor uses 32 bit addresses so it can address 2<sup>32</sup> discrete memory locations (4Gb).

Answer (score 0):

Normally char is 1 byte and guaranteed by the C and C++ standards.

Answer (score 0):

How do you come up with:

> According to the following program a char needs 4 bytes

First of all your compiler should have produced warnings when compiling, your printf expects an `int` value, you pass a `char*`. Use `sizeof()` to determine the memory footprint of any type.

Comment: I am sorry It was %p , not %d.